# Including monaco-editor into a page where requirejs is already loaded/available

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to include the `loader.js` in an environment where `requirejs` is already loaded?

What I saw is that monaco-editor is using its own loader, which also exposes `require`. It seems when I async load the loader, it doesn't bind the new one automatically. Is there a way to trigger this? Already tried to call `AMDLoader.init()`, but in that case, I'm unable to configure the config.

Once I call `require.config({paths: {'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.11.1/min/vs'}});`, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of null`